# Jqplot bar's margin/border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, flot

I'm trying to make the next design with [jqplot library](http://www.jqplot.com/):

[image]

I have make almost work but I can't put a color margin/border on each bar, anyone knows how can I make it?

Comment: what is color margin ? can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek I have changed the image for a more specific

Comment: does my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Here in the reference of Styling:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html

fillAndStroke

```
this.fillAndStroke = false
```

If true will stroke the line (with color this.color) as well as fill under it.  Applies only when fill is true.

so you will have to set it to `true` first , then set `this.color="your color";`

Comment: I have tried with `series:[{fill:true, fillAndStroke:true, color:'#ccc', fillColor:'#000'}]` but it doesn't put any margin/border on the bars, it only changes the bar color.

Comment: @iberck check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v2KQA/108/ , i played around with bar renderer soruce code , it appears that stroke color is not applied unless fill is set to false , you may try with fill Alpha if you awnt though to achieve same effect in your image.

Comment: Thank you for your time @ProllyGeek, this is exactly I was finding

Comment: @iberck is this what you want ? you havent even asked how to do it ? :D , anyway take my advice and use d3 better.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I have tried to put a filled bar with your jqplot.barRenderer.js version and with fillAlpha, fillColor but I can't get the image result. I have finding in the BarRenderer.js code but without positive results.

Comment: @iberck do you have to use jqplot ?

Comment: I have work completed with jqplot, what other js opensource library you recommend for chart?

Comment: @iberck d3.js : http://d3js.org/ , or chart.js which is much easier : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction

Comment: @iberck i have tried but it doesnt work , it always fills whole bar without drawing a stroke.

Comment: @iberck maybe we can open issue on github , but it may be time before author replies , depends.

Comment: @iberck can i have issue link please ?